# How to correctly set the `maxSupportedTransactionVersion` on `getTransaction()` function

Tags: web3.js, jsonrpc-api

When I am using private RPC and try to get an older transaction, it brings back nothing, while if use a public one it gets the transaction. I think this is because I am not setting `maxSupportedTransactionVersion`.

So how to set this parameter correctly? What is the version I have to use? Where I can get a version?

Answer (score 2):

> what is the version I have to use? Where I can get a version?

[Transaction versions are discussed in the Solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/versioned-transactions).

There's `0` and `legacy` (yes, there's a version before `0`, although this seems very unintuitive):

> The Solana runtime supports two transaction versions:
>
> - legacy - older transaction format with no additional benefit
> - 0 - added support for Address Lookup Tables